# use simplexml_load_string to load xml loss array

Tags: php

I want to import xml to database.
When I use simplexml_load_string to load this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <Item title="A">
    <Media type="pic" name="B"/>
    <Media type="pic" name="C"/>
  </Item>
  <Item title="D">
    <Media type="pic" name="E"/>
  </Item>
</data>

$xml = simplexml_load_string($fp);
$json = json_encode($xml, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

This will miss array[0] on `Media E` when Item has only 1 element.

```
                    ...
                    [Media] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => pic
                                            [name] => B
                                        )

                                )

                            ...


                    [Media] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => pic
                                    [name] => E
                                )

                        )

                ...
```

so this code will cause error.

```
foreach ($array['Item'] as $key => $value) {
  $Aarr['title'] = $value['@attributes']['title'];
  //$sql->Insert($table, $Aarr);

  foreach ($value['Media'] as $key2 => $value2) {
    $Barr['name'] = $value2['@attributes']['name'];
    //$sql->Insert($table2, $Barr);  
  }
}
```

How to have Media array[0] on `Media E`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `json_encode`/`json_decode`, you could build the array yourself by walking the `SimpleXMLElement` you're loading your XML string into:

```php
$xml     = simplexml_load_string($fp);
$collect = ['Item' => []];

foreach($xml->Item as $item) {

    // Mimic how your original array is build...
    $attributes = (array) $item->attributes();
    $items      = ['@attributes' => $attributes['@attributes'], 'Media' => []];

    foreach ($item->Media as $media) {

        //...but make sure every media item is numerically indexed
        $items['Media'][] = (array) $media->attributes();
    }

    $collect['Item'][] = $items;
}
```